# How do I change a string into valid wikipedia page name?

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to take a phrase like "banana tree" and send it directly to a wikipedia url like "Banana_tree". I know it has to follow the rules as outlined (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Page_name). Is there a JavaScript package that automatically formats it correctly without trial and error, and doing multiple api requests?

Comment: Use their search api

Answer (score 1):

I dont know that this is the most sound way of solving the problem, but this may help.

```
string.replace(/\s\s+/g, '_'); // replaces all whitespace with '_'
string.substring(0, 0).toUpperCase();//makes first char upper case
```

As I said, this may not be the fool proof answer but it may help.